# MultipleObjectsReturned when using get_or_create

Tags: python, django

I have this succinct code to get or create a conversation for current user:

```
c, created = Conversation.objects.get_or_create(
    message__sender=request.user,
    content_type=get_content_type(request.POST['ct']),
    object_id=request.POST['oid'],
    defaults={'subject': request.POST['subject']}
)
```

The problem is with this line `message__sender=request.user`; when there's more than one message, I am getting `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.

I had come around with this ugly solution to make it work as I want:

```
try:
    c = Conversation.objects.filter(
        message__sender=request.user,
        content_type=get_content_type(request.POST['ct']),
        object_id=request.POST['oid']
    )[0]
except IndexError:
    c = Conversation.objects.create(
        subject=request.POST['subject'],
        content_type=get_content_type(request.POST['ct']),
        object_id=request.POST['oid']
    )
```

Any idea how I can fix the first, cleaner version?

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with raising & catching exceptions!
Here's another option

```
try:
    result = Model.objects.get(...)
except Model.DoesNotExist:
    result = Model.objects.create(...)
```

Comment: That will return MultipleObjectsReturned after the second message is added.

Comment: Probably not unless you're creating objects outside of a get or create like this. If it exists the second time, it would just get that one.

Comment: @KevinLondon That's correct until I add this line to the mix: message__sender=request.user... then I get several rows.